# \section{\large \protect{\footnote{\url{}}}} => ! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.<inserted text>\par \begin{document}

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, urls

When I run the code for the first time(or after cleaning generated files), it works.
But after that, when I run it again, with the ***same exact code***, it spews out the error message saying:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.<inserted text>\par \begin{document}
```

What's wrong with you LaTeX...

Example Code:

```
    \documentclass[letter]{article}
    \usepackage[cjk]{kotex}
    \usepackage{CJKutf8}
    \usepackage{hyperref,url}
    \setlength{\textheight}{10in}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
    \setlength{\voffset}{-1.5in}
    \setlength{\hoffset}{-0.825in}
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{0in}
    \setlength{\marginparpush}{0in}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
    
    \begin{document}
    \section{\large 실패한 교육정책 사례 - 중학교 자유학기제 도입\protect\footnote{박재형, ``[2013-1] 중학교 자유학기제 도입,'' 교육부, \url{https://moe.go.kr/boardCnts/view.do?boardID=425&lev=0&statusYN=C&s=moe&m=0403&opType=N&boardSeq=53085} Mar 28, 2014.}}\normalsize
    \end{document}
```

I want to know what's causing it and ways to address it.

If there's already a same question out there, please let me know. I would appreciate it.

But don't blame me, I already tried googling it,
To no avail. apparently.

Thanks, TeX users!

Comment: the second run is not the same code, that is why you need to run latex more than once. On the first run there is no table of contents or bookmarks code but this is generated and input on the next run so if it has an error you see the error only on later runs. As you presumably do not want the footnot ein the table of contents nor a font size change use `\section[simple text]{longer form with \footnote[...}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I'll try that out and share the results.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That worked. Think I may take a look at the generated code too.

Comment: Try using `\protect\url`.